# Rails button_to...how to render as a <button> element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

Using the this `button_to` helper:

```
<%= button_to "Add Beer", "/growlers/create", method: "get" %>
```

yields the following HTML:

```
<form action="/growlers/create" class="button_to" method="get">
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Add Beer" />
</div>
</form>
```

Which is exactly what is supposed to happen. However, as you can see, the HTML element is a `<form>`. **I am wondering how to render this as a `<button>` for styling purposes** (using Foundation).

I found this:

```
<%= link_to "<button>Add Beer</button>".html_safe, "/growlers/create", method: "get" %>
```

yields this HTML:

```
<a data-method="get" href="/growlers/create">
<button>Add Beer</button>
</a>
```

Which, though a `<button>`, doesn't seem perfect to me.

I am curious if there are any other solutions/workarounds to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap your button label in the `button_to` statement:

```
<%= button_to "/growlers/create", method: "get" do %>
  Add Beer
<% end %>
```

It will render the wrapped text within a  element inside the form.
props to apidock: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `button_tag`?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag